# Jooq Postgres JSON query

Tags: json, postgresql, jooq

What support is there for querying into postgres json objects with JOOQ?

For example,

```
SELECT id, data->'author'->>'first_name' as author_first_name FROM books;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Many standard SQL/JSON operators like [`JSON_ARRAY()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-array-function/), [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-object-function/), [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-arrayagg-function/) and a few more are supported starting from jOOQ 3.14.

Currently (as of jOOQ 3.15), support for these vendor specific JSON operators is still not implemented: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10018

However, you can always resort to using [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). Your query can be expressed as such with jOOQ:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(BOOKS.ID, field("{0}->'author'->>'first_name'", 
                       String.class, BOOKS.DATA
                     ).as("author_first_name"))
   .from(BOOKS)
   .fetch();
```

For details, see the [`DSL.field()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-org.jooq.QueryPart...-) methods javadocs.

#### Or, write your own mini API

If you're using a lot of these JSON path notations, you might be able to factor out a mini API as such:

```
public static Field<Object> jsonObject(Field<?> field, String name) {
    return DSL.field("{0}->{1}", Object.class, field, DSL.inline(name));
}

public static Field<String> jsonText(Field<?> field, String name) {
    return DSL.field("{0}->>{1}", String.class, field, DSL.inline(name));
}
```

The above could then be used as such:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(BOOKS.ID, jsonText(jsonObject(BOOKS.DATA, "author"), "first_name")
                     .as("author_first_name"))
   .from(BOOKS)
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Just a comment on this.  I understand how to use Plain SQL to manually handle the Postgres JSON data type, but it would be nice if there were a way to get the `UpdatableRecord` to support json, even if in a slightly hackish way. We use `create.newRecord( MY_TABLE, MyPojo )` all the time and I haven't found an elegant way to handle INSERT or UPDATE for json columns.

Comment: @JoshPadnick: What kind of `INSERT` or `UPDATE` would you want to be doing? Just plain data, or some JSON function calls? Best ask a new question, though. It'll be easier to answer than with comments...

Comment: is this answer still a viable solution now?

Comment: @Brunaldo: Thanks for the ping. Slightly outdated, but in this particular case, yes, the `->` operator and the likes are not yet supported. See the workarounds offered in my answer.